What are the challenges associated with using lithium hydride as a rocket fuel?
Setting aside issues of cost and toxic exhaust products, what are the difficulties of using LiH in a rocket engine? Is it corrosive?
Related question here:
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185248/has-lithium-hydride-ever-been-tested-as-a-rocket-fuel
I know about the Rocketdyne Tripropellant rocket that burned H2, Li, and F2 together but I'm interested in rockets that use LiH
One of the comments pointed to this section of the wikipedia entry but both the citation links are broken:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydride#Hydrogen_storage_and_fuel
LiH also gets mentioned as a NTR propellant here:
Alternative propellants in nuclear thermal rockets

Your tags include "liquid fuel" but lithium hydride melts at over 600 °C. That to me suggests a bit of a challenge...

@Cadence fair enough. One thing I'm curious about is whether LiH has lower melting eutectics with methylithium or other hydrides. But I'll probably have to ask that in a separate question on chemistry.
